# sync between local and virtual machine

Tags: windows, synchronization

I'm working on a windows platform and want to be able to **auto** sync my files one way **'on change'** to my virtual windows or linux web server - also need to be able to filter file types. i can connect to the remote machine via network drives.

i'm ideally looking for a free, easy to set up solution - a commercial product that does what I need is called [ViceVersa](http://www.tgrmn.com/) but its a little overkill and costs :)

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use rsync - simple, easy to setup, and provides the filters you need.  Also very low on bandwidth after the first pass.

[Here](http://optics.ph.unimelb.edu.au/help/rsync/rsync_pc1.html) is a link explaining how to get it working in Windows

Whilst rsync doesn't allow 'on-change' auto-syncing, it is very fast when it scans a sync'ed directory (even very large ones), so you could schedule a frequent sync to overcome this.

Edit: You could combine it with a program like [this](http://www.safe-install.com/programs/watchdirectory.html), to trigger an rsync on folder contents change.  Cheaper than viceversa

Comment: can't see how this detects file changes to auto sync 'on change'

Comment: I'd be very surprised to find *any* windows software that achieves this.  ViceVersa, as you provided, schedules 'jobs' to run daily,weekly,etc - so doesn't handle on-change.
Under linux, software built into the filesystem achieves this (e.g. inotify), that detects file changes.  

Now that I look, .net has an api call (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_members.aspx), that allows you to set these up.

Comment: "You can run ViceVersa software on-demand, at scheduled times or continuously, while monitoring files for changes" http://www.tgrmn.com/web/file_synchronization.htm

Comment: Yeah - just looked again, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

For other users, its worth mentioning [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/), it will auto sync on changes between two machines (by default deferring to rsync).  Will only work on Linux though, but if thats not a problem it works great.

It also seems that [Sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/) has finally released some working code (Dropbox clone).  Havent tried it myself but does cross-platform synching and you can setup your own server.